# Custom metric API server not in Go

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-hpa

I want to implement custom metric API server to use with HPA. we have proprietary monitoring system that have client library in C# but all the implementation i saw online are in Go.

Is there a definition of REST API (request and response) that the HPA call? or this can be only in Go (for some reason)?

I can use [this](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/custom-metrics-apiserver/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md) to create a proxy server between Go and my C# server but i rather go straight to my server from HPA

Comment: hi if this answer was useful please consider upvoting or accepting it. Otherwise you can add a followup question.

Answer (score 0):

`types.go` files are the source of truth for Kubernetes API definitions. All other definition formats are generated from these files. You can find files with definitions of custom metrics API here:

- [v1beta1](https://github.com/kubernetes/metrics/blob/master/pkg/apis/custom_metrics/v1beta1/types.go)
- [v1beta2](https://github.com/kubernetes/metrics/blob/master/pkg/apis/custom_metrics/v1beta2/types.go)

Script to generate swagger API definitions can be found [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/hack/gen-swagger-doc/gen-swagger-docs.sh)  but is probably not worth the trouble since the API is so simple.

> "Is there a definition of REST API (request and response) that the HPA
>   call? or this can be only in Go (for some reason)?"

From what I was able to find the original API definitions in types.go are in GO code. For some APIs other API definitions are available, but they're all generated from `types.go` files and this particular API doesn't have any other definitions pre-generated because it's not an official part of k8s APIs. I'm not 100% sure but it certainly looks like currently GO is the only way to go.